# How could I set a breakpoint when I cant locate the file/line that I want to locate in developer mode

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

How could I set a breakpoint when I cant locate the file/line that I want to locate in developer mode

Here is the developer tool mode when I click F12 in chrome.

However, the project list shown is weird now. But I certainly know the file I want to set the break point/ or line(keyword). Is it possible to locate the breakpoint in such scenario

Update:
hence the files are not maintained by me. So, I couldnt add a breakpoint(debugger) directly on the files. But I could only a developer mode via there. I just want to check values on that line.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25551397/7867822

Comment: Seems like you have no `.map` files but only the final bundles.

Comment: May I know what does it mean? This is actually on production

Comment: But is it still posiible to find that file? or even just that line.... I know the keyword

Comment: Probably not, because those bundles are minimized. That's what the `.map` file would be for. They create a translation/relationship between the original source files and the minimized production files.

Comment: Can I still locate the line in minimized files?

Comment: I have seen ppl can still locate the keywords by searching in the past... but dont know how to search in such scenior.....

Comment: you can try searching for your keyword in the files. But without a map file, debugging will be hard to impossible ... And if your keyword is just some identifier, it might even been removed by minimization ...

Comment: Actually I have the variable name. but its just I want to debug on production

Comment: A "variable name" is an identifier. And depending on the settings at build, it probably has been refactored to something else during minimization, so chances not too good, you'll find it.

Comment: May I ask, you mentioned .map, where can I find that .map? is it some configration i somewhere? I would like to see if I can see where the .map is and then try to understand the underlying

Comment: `.map` files are created during build. So -- as you said you don't maintain those files -- you would have to ask the people who are in charge of building and deploying this app for them ...

Comment: I see. Honestly,  I have those files in my local. But I dont have premission to deploy to local, and I could only run it on my local. But the behavior i saw in my local is different than the one in production. which is why I want to debug the code in production. That's where I showed you the minized files. But I have never built before. May I know where I can see the build configuration in my project? (if you maybe somehow know)

Answer (score 0):

Add `debugger;` statement where u want to break.

Comment: hence the files are not maintained by me. So, I couldnt add a breakpoint there. But I could only a developer mode via there